# keycloak 21.0.1 authentication endpoint - Unexpected error

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, keycloak, redhat

After upgrading my keycloak instance to version 21.0.1 (the last one) from the 16.1, I'm facing the following error trying to authentication client on this endpoint:

```
realms/"myrealm"/protocol/openid-connect/auth
```

It should ask for username/password with a login mask UI, instead I receive an exception:

> Unexpected error when handling authentication request to identity provider.

Looking at the logs this is the first part of the Exception stack:

```
2023-03-21 10:23:17,275 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-50) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.BaseHttpRequest.getFormParameters(BaseHttpRequest.java:53)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.BaseHttpRequest.getDecodedFormParameters(BaseHttpRequest.java:74)
        at org.keycloak.services.HttpRequestImpl.getDecodedFormParameters(HttpRequestImpl.java:62)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.directgrant.ValidateUsername.retrieveUsername(ValidateUsername.java:161)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.directgrant.ValidateUsername.authenticate(ValidateUsername.java:52)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:445)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:249)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1025)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:887)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.handleBrowserAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:153)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildAuthorizationCodeAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:363)
```

With the following error:

```
2023-03-21 10:23:17,361 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-50) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=*******, clientId=*****,
userId=null, ipAddress=*******, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_typ
e=code, redirect_uri=************, code_id=64b4911b-e9bf-4574-a6c6-bdd62951f23a, respons
e_mode=query, authSessionParentId=64b4911b-e9bf-4574-a6c6-bdd62951f23a, authSessionTabId=XguMC_VfO70
```

For sure, it is some my lack of knowledge but I cannot understand while it is expecting username/password since I'm going on such endpoint to insert them.
Therefore it raises an exception since it found "null" the fields username/password.

The openid-client client had been imported from the previous version as well as realm configuration, when it is used to work. Nevertheless, I tried different configuration and query parameters without success.

How do I solve this problem?